# Excel: IF statement referencing other file

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula

I am having a #NAME? error in excel with the following formula

```
=IF([DOP_data_EN.xls]Feuil1!P2="Yes";"Oui";"Non")
```

Basically, what I am trying to achieve is this:
cells in this row in the original file have 2 values, either *Yes* or *No*, and

I need the formula to translate it to French automatically, in another file (I cannot just work in another sheet).

Would anyone have any guidance regarding this?

Thanks in advance,
Antoine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`#NAME?` error appears if there is a typo. Try to check everything: eg. are you sure the file has .xls extension, not .xlsx ?

Comment: Thanks for the reply!
Yes the file name is correct, other rows contain numeric values which are referenced from the original file as well.

Comment: Found what the issue was, I'm used to working in English but the software is in French: I just had to write =SI instead of =IF